# What is the distribution of the total number of parrots at time $t$ given that the total number of birds seen at time $t$ is $n$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Parrots and crows are visiting your backyard. They arrive according to
>   independent Poisson processes with rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$,
>   respectively.
>
> What is the distribution of the total number of parrots at time $t$
>   given that the total number of birds seen at time $t$ is $n$?

My idea was to use that the distribution of the total number of birds at time $t$ is given by a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda+\mu$.
Then use something like $P(\#birds = n)=P(\#crows = m)P(\#parrots = n-m)$

Which leads to $P(\#parrots)=\frac{m!(\mu+\lambda)^n}{n!\mu^m}e^{-\lambda}$.

But this is not really going anywhere.

I probably need to do something with that it's a stochastic process, but I really just don't see what I have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_t$ denote the number of parrots at time $t$ and let $Y_t$ denote the number of crows at time $t$.

$$\begin{aligned}P\left(X_{t}=k\mid X_{t}+Y_{t}=n\right) & =\frac{P\left(X_{t}=k\wedge Y_{t}=n-k\right)}{P\left(X_{t}+Y_{t}=n\right)}\\
 & =\frac{P\left(X_{t}=k\right)P\left(Y_{t}=n-k\right)}{P\left(X_{t}+Y_{t}=n\right)}\\
 & =\frac{e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^{n-k}}{\left(n-k\right)!}}{e^{-\lambda-\mu}\frac{\left(\lambda+\mu\right)^{n}}{n!}}\\
 & =\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{n-k}
\end{aligned}
$$So we are dealing with binomial distribution equipped with parameters $n$ and $p=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$.